# How to implement automated scroll in Appium with Webdriverio + Mocha?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, appium

I am automating test cases for a mobile application built with react. I am using Appium framework, and the client I am using is Webdriver.io, along with Mocha and Chai for assertions.

So far my scripts are running well, but I am facing a problem with scrolling. I have looked at Webdriver.io documentation for scrolling and have implemented touchAction(), touchPerform(), execute(), scrollTo() but no methods are working in this case. Can anyone help me with this?

This is the sample code I am using

```
var webdriverio = require("webdriverio");
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var config = require("./helpers/desiredCapabilities").options;
var client = webdriverio.remote(config);

describe("Sample Test", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
  this.timeout(90000);
});

describe("Scroll Test", function() {
  before(function() {
    return client.init();
  });

  it("should scroll successfully", function() {
    return client
      .element("~mobile")
      .setValue("1000000000")
      .element("~continue")
      .click()
      .element("~passwordTextField")
      .setValue("12345")
      .element("~continue")
      .click()
      .element("~home")
      .touchPerform([{
          action: 'press', 
          options: {x: 60, y: 200}
       },
       {
          action:'moveTo', 
          options: {x: 700, y: 200}
       },
       {
          action: 'release'
       }
    ])
    .element("~article")
    .click()
  });
 });
});
```

This code simulates a simple login operation, it works perfectly until touchPerform(), where it does not perform any scrolling.

This is the desired capabilities as required by Appium.

```
exports.options = {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    platformName: "android",
    platformVersion: "5.1",
    appPackage: "com.sample.app",
    appActivity: "com.sample.app.MainActivity",
    automationName: "uiautomator2",
    avdReadyTimeout: "2000",
    deviceName: "AVY9K17424903794",
    app: "C:/Users/MdArifuzzaman/Arif/Appium Test/app-universal- 
          release.apk",
    newCommandTimeout: 90
  },
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 4723
};
```

and this is my package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "sampletest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha scrollTest"
  },
  "author": "Md. Arifuzzaman",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "appium": "^1.7.2",
    "appium-uiautomator2-driver": "^1.1.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "mocha": "^5.0.0",
    "wd": "^1.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "randomstring": "^1.1.5",
    "wdio-appium-service": "^0.2.3",
    "wdio-mocha-framework": "^0.5.12",
    "webdriverio": "^4.10.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´am not sure if this awnser will help you aswell on mobile. But I think it should.

To scroll down:

```
client
.url('https://www.yourwebsite.com')
.leftClick('#yourtable') // <-- should also work with .click()
.scroll(0, 500) // the higher the more we scroll
```

to use keys make sure to click on the list div box before that the emulated mouse is at the item you want to scroll down. Then you can press the down key to go down:

```
 /*
  \uE014    "ArrowRight"
  \uE015    "ArrowDown"
 */

client
.leftClick('#yourtable') // <-- should also work with .click()
.keys('ArrowDown')
.keys('ArrowDown')
.keys('ArrowDown')
// or
.keys('\uE015')
.keys('\uE015')
.keys('\uE015')
```

Source: [api/protocol/keys.html](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/keys.html)